# GORM omit fields in a JSON Response

Tags: json, rest, http, go, go-gorm

I would like to omit some fields in my JSON Response.
Currently I have a type receiver that returns a new struct `userToJson`.
I then pass this to the `json.NewEncoder()`. However I am wondering if this is the best way to omit fields using GORM.

Thank you beforehand!

```
package server

import (
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    FirstName string `gorm:"not null;default:null"`
    LastName  string `gorm:"not null;default:null"`
    Email     string `gorm:"not null;default:null;unique"`
    Password  string `gorm:"not null;default:null"`
    Posts     []Posts
}
type userToJson struct {
    Email string
    Posts []Posts
}

func (u *User) toJson() userToJson {
    return userToJson{
        Email: u.Email,
        Posts: u.Posts,
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want those fields completely ignored by the `json` package, you can add a `json:”-“` tag.

Comment: @Behrooz I tried that earlier, but then unfortunately my POST route to create the User will stop working. It won't pass any JSON that I am sending to my POST route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach is to implement the interface `Marshaler` for your type to modify how marshaling to JSON works. The `json` package checks for that interface before marshaling, and if it exists, calls that function. Here is the interface from the standard library.

```golang
type Marshaler interface {
    MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)
}
```

One sample implementation for your `User` type would be as follows.

```golang
func (u *User) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    type Temp struct {
        Email string
        Posts []Post
    }

    t := Temp{
        Email: u.Email,
        Posts: u.Posts,
    }
    return json.Marshal(&t)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should declare you struct with a json tag for all fields, what Behrooz suggested in the comment should work fine

```
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    FirstName string `json:"-" gorm:"not null;default:null"`
    LastName  string `json:"-" gorm:"not null;default:null"`
    Email     string `json:"email" gorm:"not null;default:null;unique"`
    Password  string `json:"-" gorm:"not null;default:null"`
    Posts     []Posts`json:"posts"`
}
```